# How to set title in WPF without refresh all window page

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Hi !
I have a WPF application and I want to set the title of the window page without refresh the all page, because in this page I have two buttons that list a DataRow belong the Title when I press it.

```
void refreshStatusBar()
    {

            this.Title= "Holaaa";

    }
```

WPF class:

```
<Height=.... Title="Prueba"...> the initial value
```

The problem is when I press a button (next or back) I need to set the Title of the page and never change when I call to refreshStatusBar() in the btNext or btBack method.

I tryed to binding the Title, but don´t work. Always show the same value, the initial:

```
Title="{Binding Path="windowTitleBar"}"


public String windowTitleBar {get; set;}

void refreshStatusBar(){
   windowTitleBar="Holaaa";
 }
```

I want the title change when I press some button. I don´t have pages inside the window page, just show one thing or another thing.

I tryed too:

```
Title="{Binding Path=windowTitleBar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
```

and don´t work neither.

Please, any solution to fix it?

Sorry for my english !

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a window or more than one window, are you using MVVM or are your programming code behind? to use bind properly you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` otherwise it will not work

Comment: Just a window, and I use MVVM. I will try with INotifyPropertyChanged, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This works for me without a binding:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = "Hellooo";
    }

    void RefreshStatusBar()
    {
        this.Title = "Holaaa";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshStatusBar();
    }
}
```

If you want to use a binding, set it up like you did with `Title="{Binding Path=WindowTitleBar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"`

But as it is, WPF has no way of knowing when your property value changes. You can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to solve this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _windowTitleBar = "Hellooo";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.WindowTitleBar = "Hellooo";

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public string WindowTitleBar
    {
        get { return _windowTitleBar; }
        set
        {
            _windowTitleBar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WindowTitleBar");
        }
    }

    void RefreshStatusBar()
    {
        this.WindowTitleBar = "Holaaa";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshStatusBar();
    }
}
```

### Edit:

I just noticed you said "Page". I've never used Pages, but it looks like to set the title of the window containing your page, you have to set the `WindowTitle` property. Unfortunately it's not a DependencyProperty so you can't use a binding. You can set it directly, though:

```
void RefreshStatusBar()
{
    this.WindowTitle = "Holaaa";
}
```

Comment: Where does this `WindowTitle` property come from?

Comment: It's a [property of `Page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.windowtitle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok, I use WindowTitle as a value, not as property of Page, thanks !

Comment: I will try with INotifyPropertyChanged !!